Economics migration criteria
The Economics SE is now in private beta (link might not work yet) and before it goes public and we gain the ability to migrate to it, I'd like to discuss the criteria we use to determine if an economics question is on-topic for Bitcoin. Certain questions are obviously Bitcoin-centric enough to remain here, but what specific criteria do we think a question should meet to be kept or migrated?
For example, here at Bitcoin we recently fielded this question about financial analysis tools and Economics has already had 2 or 3 Bitcoin-related questions that might belong better here. Should we offload all econ questions to Economics? Are econ questions directly related to Bitcoin better addressed here with the Bitcoin experts or there with the econ experts?

Migration paths are only enabled for fully graduated sites.  In extreme cases the moderators can migrate a question and users can flag them so mods see it.  But keep in mind that a migration path is a ways off.

Wasn't talking about a full-blown migration path, I was talking about guidelines for moderator-based migration which it's my understanding can happen the moment Economics hits public beta. A lot of things are a ways off, but I already know that we'll be sending quite a few back and forth and I just wanted to establish guidelines beforehand :)

So I suppose think of it less like "migration criteria" and more like a careful definition of scope that will someday be useful in migration.

I would draw the line this way: If the question is specific to crypto-currencies, it belongs here. If not, it belongs elsewhere, once there is an elsewhere.
For example, belonging here would be questions about whether crypto-currencies will deflate, what effects crypto-currencies will have on an economy, whether a fractional reserve crypto-currency bank could exist, what affects the price and stability of crypto-currencies, and so on. Belonging elsewhere would be questions about whether a fixed monetary supply leads to deflation, whether a deflationary currency is bad, whether you can have a fixed monetary supply in a modern economy at all, and so on.

I think it's important to determine what the actual subject of the question is. Simply because it involves Bitcoin (or one of its forks) doesn't necessarily mean it's about Bitcoin. For example, Ripper's question got migrated to crypto because even though it mentioned Tenebrix it was about sCrypt.

@DavidPerry - yeah, it was a good migration.
